# Glide loader is not loading image properly

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am using Glide loader to load my images. My code is working but it changes images continuously. Here is my code:

```
Glide.with(ctx).load(image).asBitmap()        
          .dontTransform()
          .placeholder(R.drawable.cart)
          .into(new SimpleTarget < Bitmap > () {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                photoImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                               Glide.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
                                post_image.setImageBitmap(resource);
                            }
```

Comment: use cache `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) `

Comment: where i have to use this?

Comment: after `.placeholder(R.drawable.cart)` add `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) `

Comment: i have done this but its taking too much time to load

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use glide utill class for better understanding

```
public class GlideUtil {
public static void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    Context context = imageView.getContext();
    if(context!=null || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
        assert context != null;
        ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue_grey_500));

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(cd)
                .crossFade()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
    }
}

public static void loadProfileIcon(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    Context context = imageView.getContext();
    if(context!=null || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_outline_black)
                .dontAnimate()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(imageView);
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void loadImage(String url, ImageView mPhotoView, final ProgressBar mProgress) {
    Context context = mPhotoView.getContext();
    if(context!=null || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
        assert context != null;
        ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue_grey_500));

        mProgress.setEnabled(true);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .placeholder(cd)
                .crossFade()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(mPhotoView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is taking too much time to load

Comment: depends on image size or net speed you can try to resize image that can be help.

Comment: i have images of different sizes but size is not a huge?

Comment: you can try Picasso if this problem only occurred with Glide or try to add diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

Comment: picasso also take too much time

Comment: and changing images continuously

Comment: this could be your images size or resolution problem.

Comment: sir i added method which you give above..but it is loading slowly...but better then before

Comment: then it should be image resolution problem. compress your images it will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Image changing occurs because of lazy loading of images in the glide. When the glide is downloading the new image previous image will be already loaded since you are reusing the view. To prevent this,.Before loading images clear the previous image before loading image.

```
Glide.clear(post_image);
```

**EDIT**:
Also before fetching the image from glide clear the old image of the imageView.

```
post_image.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Then load the new image from glide

```
Glide.with(ctx)
     .load(image)
     .asBitmap()
     .dontTransform()
     .placeholder(R.drawable.cart)
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            post_image.setImageBitmap(resource);
        }
}
```

Comment: load time is too much

Comment: It is changing again

Comment: why are you loading image from glide again inside onResouceReady?

Comment: so what i can do

Comment: follow the above code and check if issue still exists.

Comment: For me the image didn't load sometimes in recyclerview, the issue was probably because glide was showing the previous version of the image i.e null as recycler view recycles views. setting images to null and loading them again as mentioned in the answer helped me get over it .+1